# Is there a way to get substrings of Javascript strings without explicitly calling length, like C# Range?

Tags: javascript, string, substring

Currently if a string is not "known" (or causes side-effect), we need to store it into a variable in order to get n characters from the beginning and 2 lines are needed:

```js
const str = new Date().toISOString();
return str.substring(0, str.length - 1);

// This can be done in one line but the expression is evaluated twice and there's a repetition:
return new Date().toISOString().substring(0, new Date().toISOString().length - 1);
```

Is there a "clever" way we can do that in one line, like [C# Range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges)?

```cs
return new DateTimeOffset().ToString("o")[..^1];
```

Note: I know internally `length` is probably called. This is not a question for optimization but a way to write shorter (and hopefully, clearer) code.

Comment: `const str = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, -1);`

Comment: @CBroe thanks, this is what I am looking for. I didn't know there is that difference between `substring` and `slice`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)?

```js
console.log(new Date().toISOString().slice(0,-1))
console.log(new Date().toISOString().slice(11,-5))
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know slice could accept negative parameters. I didn't notice [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring#differences_between_substring_and_slice) (i.e. it only works for `slice` but not `substring`)